# Not enough memory resources error with hresult 0x80070008 in x86 opencv

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, dll, 32bit-64bit

After adding opencv4.1.0 to my project, I started to get an error like this :

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'xxx.dll' or one of its dependencies. Not enough memory resources are available to process this command. (HResult : 0x80070008)
```

I think the problem is occcuring while all opencv dll files allocate from memory. But the memory usage was only %20. Before linking the opencv memory usage was ~800mb, after linking its increase to 1000mb.

I have already tried to increase "IRPSTackSize", cleaning temp folder but they are not works.

The annoying point is, its sometimes working but generally not working and facing that error. Is there anyway to solve that ?

Comment: We can't know where the error is coming from, if you don't show us any code examples.

Comment: Actually its not about the code, Its about the memory and x86/x64 architecture. The project is working very well but going crash after calling the opencv dlls. Opencv code is working in Visual Studio but when i get a Release Version and try to run in different computer, its going crash

Comment: It's _always_ about the code.

Comment: After calling the opencv dll's project is crashing regardless of code. I am asking about is there anyway for calling specific opencv dll's or something else ?

Comment: If you show us your code or your build process, we might be able to reproduce your problem and give advice on how to fix it.